# Get texture filename from Maya python script?

Tags: python, maya

I'm writing a python script to output a scene to a simple, readable file.

I've successfully outputted the position, rotation, scale and mesh name, but how do I get the filename of the texture that is applied to a mesh?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
meshesWithoutShape = []
meshes = cmds.ls("mesh_*")
for mesh in meshes:
    if("Shape" not in mesh):
        meshesWithoutShape.append(mesh)

shapesInSel = cmds.ls(dag=1,o=1,s=1)
shadingGrps = cmds.listConnections(shapesInSel,type='shadingEngine')
shaders = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shadingGrps),materials=1)
fileNode = cmds.listConnections('%s.color' % (shaders[0]), type='file')
currentFile = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % fileNode[0])

for mesh in meshesWithoutShape:
    print("\n" + mesh.rstrip('1234567890'))

    print round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" % mesh), 2), round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateY" % mesh), 2), round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateZ" % mesh), 2)

    print cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateX" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateY" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateZ" % mesh)

    print cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleX" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleY" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleZ" % mesh)

    fileNode = cmds.listConnections('%s.color' % (shaders[0]), type='file')
    currentFile = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % fileNode[0])
    print currentFile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ls to list all file nodes and get texture path ?

```
allFileNodes = cmds.ls(et="file")
for eachFile in allFileNodes:
    currentFile = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % eachFile)
```

If you want to get if from selection or specific mesh

```
shapesInSel = cmds.ls(dag=1,o=1,s=1,sl=1)
shadingGrps = cmds.listConnections(shapesInSel,type='shadingEngine')
shaders = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shadingGrps),materials=1)
fileNode = cmds.listConnections('%s.color' % (shaders[0]), type='file')
currentFile = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % fileNode[0])
```

**Update**

Here is the code you want to work with your needs

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
meshesWithoutShape = []
meshes = cmds.ls("mesh_*", tr = True)

for mesh in meshes:
    print("\n" + mesh.rstrip('1234567890'))

    print round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" % mesh), 2), round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateY" % mesh), 2), round(cmds.getAttr("%s.translateZ" % mesh), 2)

    print cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateX" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateY" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.rotateZ" % mesh)

    print cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleX" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleY" % mesh), cmds.getAttr("%s.scaleZ" % mesh)
    shadingGrps = cmds.listConnections(mesh,type='shadingEngine')
    shaders = cmds.ls(cmds.listConnections(shadingGrps),materials=1)
    fileNode = cmds.listConnections('%s.color' % (shaders[0]), type='file')
    currentFile = cmds.getAttr("%s.fileTextureName" % fileNode[0])
    print currentFile
```

Comment: Your second block of code almost does exactly what I need it to, the only issue is it gets the same texture every time. I think I'm misunderstanding what this code does, I've updated my question with my current code.

Comment: I just updated my answer also, but if you look carefully you should have got that fairly easy :)

Comment: I'd tried this format as well, but I run into an issue:"Warning: No objects specified that can have connections." This is where it's trying to make shadingGrps

Comment: Hey I just gave you the most simple explanation "how can you do this"..